# What is a bleed-thru file in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I was doing a checkout of a file in ClearCase, and I was unable to checkout this file from the frozen view because of this file which was a bleed-thru file.  I thawed the view, and then I was able to check out the file, so I really do not have a problem at this time.

I do have a question, though.  What is a bleed-thru file in ClearCase?  Any ideas?  I have not heard this term before, and was interested, partly because it just sounds so cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you call a "frozen view", except if you are referring to a snapshot view.
A "bleed-through" file (again, I am not familiar with the 'bleed-thru' spelling) could be related to multi-site views, where:

> This navigator is called a "bleed through" view because it lists both local files/members and remote objects, files and members.
>   However, if a file or member exists both locally and remotely, it is not shown twice.
>   Rather, it is only shown once, and its icon and bracketed text identify it as existing in both places.

If you have any screen captures of that term used in ClearCase, I am interested;)

Comment: Actually, that would explain it.  I apologize that I did not do a screen capture at the time.  I think that the bleed-thru spelling comes from an internal wrapper script that we use in-house.  I am not sure if "bleed-thru" or "bleed-through" is the proper spelling, but I am assuming that you are probably right about the spelling.

The scenario that you described of having a local file and a remote file in my case would be a possible scenario for that, and as I'd imagine, that would happen for multi-site views due to the nature of ClearCase.

Makes sense, and thanks!